# Is it possible to send the result of a steam operation to another function without collecting it in another variable

Tags: java, kotlin, collections, java-8, stream

For example, in Kotlin/java I have a list of Strings. I have filtered the list and passed it through a mapping function. In the end I can collect it into another list and then use that list anywhere I want like send it to another function. Is there any way to send the output list to another function without explicitly collecting it? Code snippet below:

```
val resultantList = stringList.filter { it.startsWith("a") }
            .map { it.substringAfter("b") }
anotherFunction(resultantList)
```

In the above piece of code I dont want to declare resultantList. Instead, at the end of map, can I pass the result to 'anotherFunction` directly. Something like

```
stringList.filter { it.startsWith("a") }
            .map { it.substringAfter("b") }.<something>{anotherFunction(it)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[let](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) is what you are looking for. You don't even have to call `.let { anotherFunction(it) }` but can use a function reference `.let(::anotherFunction)`